# WPF GridViewColumnHeader.Click - Get ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, itemssource

I have a WPF page, where I have several `ListViews`.
I want to sort my lists when clicking on `headers`, for this there is no problem, but for now I make a separate function for each ListView, I would like to make a common function.

Let's say I would like to replace that :

```
contexte.ListeDesAssemblagesView.SortDescriptions.Clear();
contexte.ListeDesAssemblagesView.SortDescriptions.Add(monsort);
```

By something like :

```
sender.ItemsSource.SortDescriptions.Clear();
sender.ItemsSource.SortDescriptions.Add(monsort);
```

Edit : Here is the code of my function modified thanks to mm8.

```
void GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewColumnHeader headerClicked = e.OriginalSource as GridViewColumnHeader;
    ListSortDirection direction;
    ListView listView = sender as ListView;
    ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listView.ItemsSource);

    string header = "";
    if (headerClicked.Column.DisplayMemberBinding != null)
    {
        header = ((System.Windows.Data.Binding)headerClicked.Column.DisplayMemberBinding).Path.Path;
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            DataTemplate cellTemplate = headerClicked.Column.CellTemplate;
            Grid grid = cellTemplate.LoadContent() as Grid;
            TextBlock textBlock = grid.Children.OfType<TextBlock>().FirstOrDefault();
            header = BindingOperations.GetBinding(textBlock, TextBlock.TextProperty).Path.Path;
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }

    string lastHeaderName = view.SortDescriptions[0].PropertyName;
    string lastDirection = view.SortDescriptions[0].Direction.ToString();
    if (headerClicked != null)
    {
        if (headerClicked.Role != GridViewColumnHeaderRole.Padding)
        {
            if (header != lastHeaderName)
            {
                direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
            }
            else
            {
                if (lastDirection == "Ascending")
                {
                    direction = ListSortDirection.Descending;
                }
                else
                {
                    direction = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
                }
            }
            if (header != "")
            {
                SortDescription monsort = new SortDescription(header, direction);
                view.SortDescriptions.Clear();
                view.SortDescriptions.Add(monsort);  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you hook up the event handler?

Comment: I'm not sure I undertand the question(what does hook up mean?), I use GridViewColumnHeader.Click event.

Comment: ListeDesAssemblagesView is an ICollectionView, it is my ListView ItemsSource

Comment: yes just read it, I am testing it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you hook up the event handler to the `ListViews` in your XAML markup like this:

```
<ListView GridViewColumnHeader.Click="GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler">
```

...you could simply cast the `sender` argument:

```
void GridViewColumnHeaderClickedHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListView listView = sender as ListView;
    ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listView.ItemsSource);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot, found how to make it a global function to implement it to all of my ListViews :) (edited my question with it)